# Match html output for result scrapy (skip first match)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have existing `scrapy` code, but am having trouble formulating `NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR` that will select the element via css select in `scrapy`:

```
def parse(self, response):
'''
        get the first page of results.
    '''
    SET_SELECTOR = 'b_algo'
    for bresult in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
        NAME_SELECTOR = 'h2 a ::text'
        yield {
            'name': bresult.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        }

    '''
        get the further pages of results.
    '''
    #<<NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR here>>
```

The html Im trying to match is:

```
<ul class="sb_pagF" aria-label="More pages with results">
<li>
          <a title="Next page" class="sb_pagN" href="/search?q=site%3asite.com&amp;first=11&amp;FORM=PORE">
            <div class="sw_next">Next
            </div>
          </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I've formulated the following to match this:

```
NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '.sb_pagF li a ::attr(href)'
```

Does this look right to grab the `href`?

Thanks!

Comment: I wanted someone to review my select for `NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR` is correct for this subset of `html` provided

Comment: looks fine for me, you should test it in scrapy shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is correct:

```
$ scrapy shell
In[1]: foo = """<ul class="sb_pagF" aria-label="More pages with results">
<li>
          <a title="Next page" class="sb_pagN" href="/search?q=site%3asite.com&amp;first=11&amp;FORM=PORE">
            <div class="sw_next">Next
            </div>
          </a>
</li>
</ul>"""
In [2]: from scrapy import Selector
In [3]: sel = Selector(text=foo)
In [4]: sel.css('.sb_pagF li a ::attr(href)').extract()
Out[1]: [u'/search?q=site%3asite.com&first=11&FORM=PORE']
```

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks @Granitosaurus !

Comment: Would this selector work too? `.sb_pagF li a.sb_pagN ::attr(href)` (if there was multiple links on a page, and this specific link was the only one with a `class=sb_pagN`) ?

Comment: No, this selector will select all links under `<li>` tags under `sb_pagF` class. To remedy this you want to isolate the next page link. Usually that is being done by selecting according got the text or class. For your example the obvious move would be to use this `a.sb_pagN::attr(href)` since `sb_pagN` is most likely a class exclusive for "page next" node.

Answer (score 3):

You can always test your selectors in the [Scrapy Shell](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) pointing it to your local html:

```
$ cat index.html
<ul class="sb_pagF" aria-label="More pages with results">
    <li>
        <a title="Next page" class="sb_pagN" href="/search?q=site%3asite.com&amp;first=11&amp;FORM=PORE">
            <div class="sw_next">Next
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
$ scrapy shell file://$PWD/index.html
In [1]: response.css(".sb_pagF li a ::attr(href)").extract_first()
Out[1]: u'/search?q=site%3asite.com&first=11&FORM=PORE'
```